# What is $\nabla_{\gamma'_t}\gamma_t'$ equal to? An attempt

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Is it correct? Let $\gamma_t$ be a smooth curve on a Riemannian mfd. Then

$\nabla_{\gamma'_t}\gamma_t'=\gamma''_t+(\gamma_t^i)'(\gamma_t^j)'\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\gamma''$?

Comment: Twice the derivative of $\gamma_t$ in local coordinates, i.e. $\gamma'_t=(\gamma^i_t)'\partial_i$ and $\gamma''_t=(\gamma^i)''\partial_i$. This is why I am not sure of what I am doing..

Comment: Then I agree with your answer!  And a reference is Do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, ch 2 (near the end. page 54 in my edition)

Comment: Thank you very much for you help and for your reference!

Comment: If you'd like, you can write your own answer and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\gamma_t$ be a smooth curve on a Riemannian manifold. Then, writing in local coordinates $\gamma'_t=(\gamma_t^i)'\partial_i$ one has that

$\nabla_{\gamma_t'}\gamma_t'=(\gamma_t^i)''\partial_i+(\gamma_t^i)'(\gamma_t^j)'\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k$.